# SQL Exception error when trying to execute the query to sqllite database

Tags: java, database, sqlite, prepared-statement, sqlexception

I am trying to query database from login application to the SQLite database. Once the user enter user name and password and clicked enter it should check the credentials in the database. When I clicked login button it is showing:

```
java.sql.SQLException:sql error or missing database
```

Below is the code for better understanding. What is the error in the code?

### Note:

- I have Login table in my database.
- The connection is successful

---

```
try
{
    String query="select * from Login where username=? Password=?";
    PreparedStatement pst=connection.prepareStatement(query);
    pst.setString(1, userField.getText());
    pst.setString(2, passwordField.getText());
    ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();
    int count=0;
    
    while(rs.next()) {
        count=count+1;
    }
    
    if(count==1) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username and Password is correct");
    }
    else if (count>1)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " Duplicate Username and Password is correct");
    }
    else
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "  Username and Password is not correct");
    }
    rs.close();
    pst.close();

} catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```

Comment: (1-) 1) I don't see the "and" keyword in the where clause of your SQL statement. 2) Why are you the `getText()` method in the setString(...) method of the PreparedStatement. Maybe that method is returning null? I suggestion you hardcode a value userid and password to test your SQL

Comment: There is a typo in your query; it should be `select * from Login where username=? and Password=?` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String query="select * from Login where username=user123 Password=password123";
PreparedStatement pst=connection.prepareStatement(query);
pst.setString(1, userField.getText());
//pst.setString(2, passwordField);
```

The basics of using a PreparedStatement should be something like:

```
String query="select * from Login where username = ? and Password = ?";
PreparedStatement pst=connection.prepareStatement(query);
pst.setString(1, userField.getText());
pst.setString(2, passwordField.getText());
```

That is the query string indicates where you want to add parameters to the string. Then you need to replace the parameters with values from the text components of your GUI.

Also, why do you have a while loop? Isn't the point of the query to determine if the userid/password are found in the database? If so there can only ever be one entry returns in the ResultSet.

Read the section on [JDBC Database Access](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html) for SQL basics.

This question has nothing to do with Swing. First learn how to do the SQL query properly by hardcoding the userid/password values in the setString(...) method. Once you get this working, then you try to do the query with dynamic data that you get from a text field in your GUI.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I tried what you suggested but same exception. And I am not able to populate the table from that database getting exception "no such table" or "null pointer exception" .But  I am able to create a table from java swing to database.Please suggest me as I am trying this from two days but could not able to solve the issue.

Comment: @Divya, well I gave you a tutorial link. Read the tutorial. We don't know what the name of the tables in your database are, or what the column names are. You created the database, so you should know all that information. There are no standard names that we can tell you to use.

Comment: Also the update to your code did not follow my suggestion. Note the "and" keyword between the two where conditions. You haven't set the value of the second parameter. `I am trying this from two days` - it would seem to me like you need to pay better attention to example code and suggestion that you are given. I suggested 4 lines (of untested code) and you made 2 mistakes. Take the time to read the answer and understand the suggestion. Take the time to read the tutorial.

Comment: `getting exception "no such table" or "null pointer exception"` - well what is it? I doubt very much you get a message with an "or" in the message. In any case fix the "Null Pointer Exception". Again we don't have access to your code so figure out which variable is null and fix the problem. That is why I suggested you hardcode the values first so you know for sure they are not null. Or as I suggested above you only set one parameter, so would the second not be null???This is basic problem solving!

Comment: Below is the code which I am not able to populate the table from database to jtabletry {
  String query="select * from tablename";
  System.out.println("query executed");
    pst=connection.prepareStatement(query);
    System.out.println("prepare statement executed"); 
   
    rs=pst.executeQuery();
   System.out.println("resultset executed");
   table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
   System.out.println("DB util executed");
   rs.close();
   pst.close();}
   
  
  
  
  catch (SQLException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

Comment: 1) Don't post code in a comment. 2) what is this code???. It is completely different that the code in your question. Don't change the question!!! If your original question is solved then "accept" the answer. Don't keep asking new questions.